# How do I apply jQuery hover script to a div class in the link being hovered over?

Tags: jquery, function, hover, this

I don't think my question is as clear as it could be, but hopefully I can make it clearer here.

I have the following hover script:

```
$("nav a#index").hover(
    function() {
        $(".current").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 300,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });
    }, function() {
        $(".current").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });
    });
```

I use it to fade in images in a div with absolute positioning:

```
<div id="nav1">
     <a href="index.html" class="fade nav top current" id="index">

     <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>

     <div id="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
     <div class="text"><img src="images/home.png"></div>

     </a>
</div>
```

Because I am needing the hover effect on multiple nav divs, e.g. nav2, nav3, etc., I need hover scripts for each of these, or rather, I am hoping to find a way of writing one script that would work for all of my nav links, so this would start with:

```
$("nav a").hover(
```

and then would have something like:

```
function() {
            $(this ".current").animate({......
```

i.e. I am looking for a way of referring to a div class in a particular a href link so that I can fade this in.  I hope this is clearer!

Thanks for any help.

Nick

Comment: `$("nav a")` looks erroneous ... it should be like `$("a.nav")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$(".current")` to `$(".current", this)`: After this modification, only the `.current` element within the link will be changed.
Modify the selector: `div[id^=nav]` will select all DIV elements whose ID start with "`nav`"

**Note**: Change `id="index"` to `class="index"`.

```
$("div[id^=nav] a.index").hover(
function() {
    $(".current", this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        specialEasing: {
            opacity: 'linear',
        },

    });
}, function() {
    $(".current", this).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        specialEasing: {
            opacity: 'linear',
        },

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$("a#index").hover(
function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".current").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        specialEasing: {
            opacity: 'linear',
        },

    });
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".current").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        specialEasing: {
            opacity: 'linear',
        },

    });
});
```